# How to pass google credential to google pub sub

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying publish to google PubSub from my .NET Core App. I have already created the PubSub and a Topic in Google PubSub. I downloaded the private key json file and included in my project. I am able to read the file and create the credential but I don't see a way to pass the credential to Google's PubSub Publisher client. I have looked at the GitHub [Post](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1576) but unfortunately I am not seeing a property named DefaultEndPoint.

Running my code generates an error which is looking for environment variable for credential. I do not want to set the environment variable for now and if there is no alternative I will try that.

Following is my code and let me know what I am doing wrong of is something that got changed recently.

var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("app-services.json");
 PublisherClient publisher = PublisherClient.CreateAsync(topicName).Result;

Answer (score 10):

Agreed that this isn't at obvious as it should be.

```
using Grpc.Auth;

var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("app-services.json");
var createSettings = new PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings(
    credentials: credential.ToChannelCredentials());
var publisher = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(topicName,
    clientCreationSettings: createSettings);
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this out this weekend and post my feedback here. This is a good as long as it gets added to the documentation for now.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a PublisherServiceApiClient without environment variables:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(@"{""your_credentials_json_itself"":""here""}");
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(PublisherServiceApiClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());
var publisher = PublisherServiceApiClient.Create(channel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "Passing the path to the service account key in code" (for .NET) here:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually

Comment: providing the path is for setting the environment variable and as I have mentioned in my question, that works but I don't want to use environment variable I rather want to pass the credential as a part of publisher client.

Comment: Please read the link I sent, it provides instructions for explicitly referencing the service account path from within code.

Comment: hi Daz, I am able to get the path and get credential and I am looking to pass credential when instantiating PublisherClient

Comment: `var PublisherServiceApiClient publisher = PublisherServiceApiClient.Create(credential);` where `var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath);` See (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library)

Comment: there is no overload method in PublisherServiceApiClient.Create() that accepts credential as a parameter. There is method that accepts channel which is what I was trying to do which I mentioned in my question

Comment: You're correct. I would expect Pub/Sub to follow the pattern as outlined for Cloud Storage but it appears to not do so. I recommend you file an issue on the GitHub repo for the SDK and ask how to achieve this. Please reference the issue here and I'll ping the DevRel team. (link: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues)